# how to sort dom-repeat items in google-polymer

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer

I have a problem in google-polymer when working with data-binding
I need to sort dom-repeat items in the polymer .
I need to write a function for sorting, and use it for all my dom-repeats

i cannot find a way.

this is my sort function:

```
 sort: function(a, b) {
          var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
          var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); 
          if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (nameA > nameB) {
            return 1;
          }
          // names must be equal
          return 0;
        }
```

how i can do it?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sort property like this :

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]" sort="sort">
      <div>{{item.name}} - {{item.age}}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      Polymer({ 
        is: 'my-element',
        properties: {
          items: {
            type: Array,
            value: [
              {name: "Saman", age: 20},
              {name: "Mahdi", age: 20},
              {name: "Erlik", age: 48}
            ]
          }
        },
        sort: function(a, b) {
          var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); 
          var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); 
          if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (nameA > nameB) {
            return 1;
          }

          // names must be equal
          return 0;
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
<my-element></my-element>
```

Ref. https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#filtering-and-sorting-lists